# Highlight element then transition back to original color

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, background-color

I have elements with different `background-color`s. When a link is clicked, I want to highlight the element with a different color (yellow), then fade back to the element's original color. I know there is `currentColor` for an element's `color`, but there's nothing similar for `background-color`.

**How can I smoothly transition from a highlight color back to the element's original `background-color`?** Right now it fades from the highlight color to transparent, then jumps abruptly back to the original color when the animation ends.

```css
:target td {
  animation: highlight 1s;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  from {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  to {
  /* How do I set this back to the element's original background-color? */
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#link1">Link #1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#link2">Link #2</a>
  </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#link3">Link #3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<table>
  <tr id="link1">
    <td>This is Link #1</td><td>// Fine.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="link2">
    <td bgcolor="orange">This is Link #2</td><td>// Ugly.</td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="link3">
    <td bgcolor="red">This is Link #3</td><td>// Ugly.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If there ever were a time when "just use jQuery" were valid… :)

Comment: But, oh! the joys of working with zero external libraries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't include a `to` for the animation. This works because if an end (or start) state is not defined, the browser will use the element's existing styles (RE: [Valid Keyframe Lists on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#Valid_keyframe_lists))

```css
div {
  margin: 200px 0;
}

:target td {
  animation: highlight 1s;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  from {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#link1">Link #1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#link2">Link #2</a>
  </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#link3">Link #3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<table>
  <tr id="link1">
    <td>This is Link #1</td><td>// Fine.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="link2">
    <td bgcolor="orange">This is Link #2</td><td>// Ugly.</td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="link3">
    <td bgcolor="red">This is Link #3</td><td>// Ugly.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `background-color: initial` on 50% of the animation - see demo below:

```css
div {
  margin: 200px 0;
}

:target td {
  animation: highlight 2s;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#link1">Link #1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#link2">Link #2</a>
  </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#link3">Link #3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<table>
  <tr id="link1">
    <td>This is Link #1</td><td>// Fine.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="link2">
    <td bgcolor="orange">This is Link #2</td><td>// Ugly.</td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="link3">
    <td bgcolor="red">This is Link #3</td><td>// Ugly.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ooh, I like this idea. Looks like it doesn't work in IE 11 though.

Answer (score 1):

if you just remove `to` from keyframes it will take the assigned background-color.

to understand it read this section of mdn doc
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#Valid_keyframe_lists

```css
div {
  margin: 200px 0;
}

:target td {
  animation: highlight 2s;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  from {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#link1">Link #1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#link2">Link #2</a>
  </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#link3">Link #3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<table>
  <tr id="link1">
    <td>This is Link #1</td><td>// Fine.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="link2">
    <td bgcolor="orange">This is Link #2</td><td>// Ugly.</td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="link3">
    <td bgcolor="red">This is Link #3</td><td>// Ugly.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```